# readableObjectMode with string

Tags: node.js, stream

I'm trying to understand how the stream works in nodejs. To do this, I wrote this code

```
'use strict'

var fs = require('fs')
var split = require('split')
var stream = require('stream')

const myTransform = new stream.Transform({
  writableObjectMode: true,
  readableObjectMode: true,
  transform (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log('transform', chunk) // chunk is a string
    this.push({chunk: chunk})
    callback()
  }
})

const myWritable = new stream.Writable({
  objectMode: true,
  write (chunk, encoding, callback) {
    console.log('writable', chunk)
    callback()
  }
})

myWritable.on('finish', () => console.log('FINISHED'))
fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/prova.txt')
  .pipe(split())
  .pipe(myTransform)
  .pipe(myWritable)
```

This example works well but I don't understand why if the transform stream  has set `readableObjectMode` to `false`, the script fails

```
transform line1
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at chunkInvalid (_stream_readable.js:380:10)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:125:12)
    at Transform.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:128:32)
    at Transform.transform [as _transform]    (/path/to/mystream.js:12:10)
    at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:167:10)
    at Transform._write (_stream_transform.js:155:12)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:301:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:287:5)
    at Transform.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:215:11)
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is not so clear but

1. `readableObjectMode` is relative to the "read side". So if true you can push an object. Otherwise a string or buffer has to be used
2. `writableObjectMode`is relative to the "write side". So the method `transform` has an object as the first parameter.

So, in the example above, the `writableObjectMode` parameter could be set to `false`.

NB: if `writableObjectMode` is set to `false`, the transform method receives an instance of `Buffer` as `chunk`